Windows Authentication in ABP.io framework
I want to implement Windows Authentication into ABP.io framework project. I want to get Windows user and login that user, if user is added into ABP.io database.
I'm using version 6.0.3 with .NET Core, MS SQL Server and Angular UI.
I'm using Authorization Code Flow, so I've overriden login page and created CustomLoginModel that extends LoginModel. In that model I've implemented Windows login like this:
var windowsUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

if (windowsUser.Contains('\\'))
{
    windowsUser = windowsUser.Split('\\')[1];
}

await IdentityOptions.SetAsync();

var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(windowsUser);

if (user == null)
{
    Alerts.Danger($"User {windowsUser} not found!");
    return Page();
}

if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user))
{
    Alerts.Warning(L["UserLockedOutMessage"]);
    return Page();
}

await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, LoginInput.RememberMe);

await IdentitySecurityLogManager.SaveAsync(new IdentitySecurityLogContext()
{
    Identity = IdentitySecurityLogIdentityConsts.Identity,
    Action = "Succeeded",
    UserName = user.UserName
});

return RedirectSafely(ReturnUrl, ReturnUrlHash);

I'm facing issue that it works when I'm running it locally and stops working when I deploy it on IIS. On IIS I'm getting user from application pool instead of actual username. Is there any other way to get Windows user?

Do you get any error messages when it stops working on iis? how do you want to get windows user? code? or other methods?

I don't get any error messages. When I try to login to the page, the above code gets user IIS APPPOOL\WindowsLogin instead of my actual username. I've also tried calling HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name, HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.User.Identity?.Name and User.Identity?.Name, but those are all null.

I think you should use ldap
LDAP External login Provider
